# How to double extend Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, layout, xml

is it possible to extend a new checkout_index_index.xml on top of already existing one

I created a

`projectA/app/design/frontend/MageBig/martfury/projecta/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`

here

and put the details.js here

`projectA/app/design/frontend/MageBig/martfury/projecta/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/summary/item/details.js`

and have it .phtml here

`projectA/app/design/frontend/MageBig/martfury/projecta/Magento_Checkout/web/template/summary/item/details.html`

but now I have a new module which need to extend a new function on top of the above already exisiting

it it possible to create a new module which have checkout_index_index.xml file like this,

`projectA/app/code/ProjectA/TrackingScript/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`

I tried to do like this but when I console.log in the new file it does not reflect anything

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to extend an existing checkout_index_index.xml file in Magento 2 by creating a new module with its own checkout_index_index.xml file. However, there are a few things to keep in mind:

1. Make sure that your new module is loaded after the module containing the original checkout_index_index.xml file. You can do this by setting a sequence in your module's module.xml file.
2. Make sure that your new checkout_index_index.xml file includes the original file using the  directive, like this:

   ```
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
      <update handle="checkout_index_index"/>
      <!-- Your customizations here -->
   </page>
   ```

This will merge your customizations with the original file.

3. Make sure that your new module is enabled and installed correctly, and that your custom JavaScript file is being loaded on the checkout page. You can check this by inspecting the page source and looking for your script file.

If you have done all of these things and are still not seeing your console logs, try clearing the Magento cache and refreshing the page. It is also possible that there is an error in your JavaScript code that is preventing it from running. You can check for errors in the browser console.

Comment: thank you, I try to find ways how to set sequence in module.xml file, I put it like this ```<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
 <module name="Wowshop_TrackingScript" setup_version="1.1.0"/
  <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
            <module name="Wowshop_TrackingScript"/>
  </sequence>
 </module>
</config>
``` but an error related to Invalid Document appear when I try setup di compile

Answer (score 0):

you need to rewrite js file with `requirejs-config.js`.

> app\code[Vendor][Namespace]\view\frontend\requirejs-config.js

```
{
    map: 
    {
        '*': 
        {
            '{path}/../details':'[Vendor]_[Namespace]/js/summary/item/details'
        }
    }
};
```

Override javascript Ref: https://meetanshi.com/blog/override-js-file-in-magento-2/